# Callback for Custom Item in Intent Chooser Screen

Tags: android, android-intent, android-intent-chooser

My use case is to download an image from a Custom Download option from Intent Chooser. I understand that I can add the custom option by adding some code like below :

```
Intent share = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
share.setType("text/plain");       
share.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, message);

Intent addIntent = ;//whatever you want

Intent chooser = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CHOOSER);
chooser.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_INTENT, share );      
chooser.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TITLE, "title");

Intent[] intentArray =  {addIntent }; 
chooser.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_INITIAL_INTENTS, intentArray);
startActivity(chooser);
```

I also have the the function in place which will download the image for me. My question is, Can I detect that the custom option was selected/clicked by the user and then set a callback to my download function directly and proceed with the download operation ?

Note : I do not want to launch any new activity during the process. Just looking for pointers on how I could possibly set a call back for this custom option in the chooser.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Can I detect that the custom option was selected/clicked by the user and then set a callback to my download function directly and proceed with the download operation ?

Only on Android 5.1+, if you use [the three-parameter flavor of `createChooser()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#createChooser%28android.content.Intent,%20java.lang.CharSequence,%20android.content.IntentSender%29), where you can supply an `IntentSender` that is notified about the choice... and then only if by "set a callback to my download function directly and proceed with the download operation" you mean "launch an activity that does the download".

Otherwise, you would need to roll your own chooser-style UI, then use the user's choice to craft an explicit `Intent` to route the user to the requested activity.

Comment: Thank you very much. That helps a lot. I guess I would go and roll my own Custom-style chooser. I will accept this answer in a couple of minutes.